# how to import contacts from php to wordpress

Tags: php

hello I have a php site with a list of already registered members who have a password.
I would like to be able to import my members into wordpress with their passwords ... how to do that. On my php site registration is done with this hash code

```
$cost = ['cost' => 12];
                            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when adding a new user using either `wp_create_user()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/) or `wp_insert_user()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) the password is passed in as a plain-text string, and the WP functions will encrypt into the wp_users table.

There are some plugins out there that will allow import from a CSV (example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/)

If you are looking at writing your own code to loop through data you can use the functions above as needed, allowing you to pass in the password string as plain-text along with other related user data.

If you are looking at creating a new password on the fly as you create the users you can use `wp_generate_password()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) and pass the returned value into the user data for the user being added.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the explanations but i'm looking for a method to import the users and passwords from my php site to wordpress. i tried with plugins to import the data in csv format, but the words passwords are not recognized

Comment: @flexi22 interesting, but this is likely because if the code you referenced is using `password_hash()` when the user is created in that system, then the passwords are all hashed.  This would not be what you need, since WP functions need plain text passed into them, and they will create the hashes as needed.

I would recommend creating random passwords and then sending all users a message seeking them to use the password reset link from the login form to create their own pswds on this site.  It seems useful to import accounts with the same pswds, but security-wise changing them would be best.

Comment: Hello
Thanks for the answer. I will take your advice and give each user a new password with a reset link